# JavaScript: How to read an input id with a jsp tag inside (id="studenttid_<%=intCount%>")

Tags: javascript, jsp

Let say I have 10 students.

I declared a variable, `intCount=0` so that I can loop the input field with their respective id.

The code for the looping input field looks like this:

```
<%intCount++%>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="studenttid_<%=intCount%>"%>"></td>
</tr>
```

After compilation, the output is:

studentid_1 
 studentid_2 
 studentid_3 
 studentid_4 
 studentid_5 
 studentid_6 
 studentid_7 
 studentid_8 
 studentid_9 
 studentid_10

Then, I need to parse the studentid_1,...,studentid_10 to my javascript, which the problem is I do not know what should I write in `document.getElementById('')`.

I tried something like:

```
<script>var studentId = document.getElementById('studentid_<%=intCount%>')</script>
```

but it returns "variable intCount is undefined". What should I do to solve my problem? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Get all input fields.
2. Filter that list for the ones that have an ID like what you are looking for.
3. Get the id property from the ones you are looking for.

You could do this with `.reduce` instead of `.filter().map()` but this is probably simpler to understand.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var inputArr = Array.apply(null, inputs);
var studenttid_elements = inputArr.filter(ele => ele.id.indexOf("studenttid_") === 0);
var studenttid_ids = studenttid_elements.map(ele => ele.id);

console.log("Elements:", studenttid_elements);
console.log("IDs", studenttid_ids);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="studenttid_1">
<input type="text" id="studenttid_2">
<input type="text" id="other_id">
```

Comment: Hi @Goblinlod, thanks for the response. I don't understand why declare input id with 1 and 2. It should be auto looped until it reaches the last id. For instance, if I have 100 students id, then it should loop until studentid_100 and parse into javascript.

Comment: The looping through to create the fields didn't seem to be what your question is really related to.  Also, they don't provide anything to use that type of template here (stackoverflow).  So I omitted it.  I instead just put some javascript that you could use no matter what for this case.  Though in your example you use `studenttid_#` and not `studentid_#`.  I assume that is a mistake but my code used the first.

Comment: Also, I guess it would really depend on what you wanted to do with `var studentid`.  The code above gives you an array of all of those elements in javascript (it is actually runnable).

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. It should be studentid_. Your solution solves my problem. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your JavaScript code within a `<script>` tag in a JSP file or in a file included in a JSP file.

`<script>var studentId = document.getElementById('studenttid_<%=intCount%>') </script>`

If your JavaScript is not within a  tag or not within a JSP file, the Jasper engine will ignore it.

Alternately, just use EL.

`'studenttid_${intCount}'`

Comment: It is inside a `<script>` tag. Updated my post.

Comment: @BrianCheong, where do you get the error `variable intCount is undefined`? In the browser console or on the server?

Comment: It is in the browser console.

Comment: So if you try `'studenttid_${intCount}'` (EL) instead of `'studenttid_<%=intCount%>'` (scriptlet), is that an issue?

Comment: Nope. It returns null. I solved the problem with the solution given by @Goblinlord. Thanks for your response.